# unbinding/destroying event for TextHighlighter library

Tags: javascript, css, web

I am using [TextHighlighter](https://github.com/mir3z/texthighlighter) library for highlighting the selected text. And I have my own custom underlining function.

Now problem occures when I try to swap from underline to highlight and vice versa both underline and highlight action occurs. I think destroying or unbinding of TextHighlighter is not working.

Is anyone having the same problem? And what may be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Destroy method of TextHighLighter does not seem to work.

You can use below fix to achieve the destroy the highlighter

```
var handler = document.getElementById('handler');

Initialize the TextHighlighter by using below code 

hltrStem = new TextHighlighter(handler, {
    onBeforeHighlight: function (range) {
        //return true/false; 
        // Return true when you want to highlight the text and return false when you want to disabled highlight
        // Use a flag which is true when you want to highlight the text and false when you want to disabled highlight
    }
});
```